# Golang installation

Tags: go, installation, go-build

I just followed the installation guide for golang (ubuntu 16).
I extracted the archive at /etc/usr
I added env variable in /home/user/.profile
I just tested a basic go build on the hello world code.

I get the following error:

```
The program 'go' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt install golang-go
```

Why does it ask me to install it (again?)?

Comment: My guess would be because it's not been properly installed to start with! Can you provide a link to the installation guide you're referring to as well as the complete and exact steps you took?

Comment: Don't include screen shots of text! Copy and paste the text directly into the question instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The location of the binary `go` is not in your path. Ubuntu does not find it and suggests to install it. Add this line to your file `/etc/profile`, or better `$HOME/.profile`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

This is documented in the docs: https://golang.org/doc/install#install

If you want to try this solution before editing any files, you can just execute the above command and try to execute the `go` command in the shell.

Answer (score 6):

1. open the go documentation download
   https://go.dev/dl/
2. choice your os and go version
3. download then extract the file
4. extract the file
5. open the file and open the terminal
   6.Add /usr/local/go/bin to the PATH environment variable.
   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
6. then check the go version
   go version

Answer (score 4):

There are paths which needs to be set correctly for you go installation to work

1. GOROOT points to directory where go is installed

   `export GOROOT=/usr/lib/go`
2. GOPATH points to you workspace directory

   `export GOPATH=$HOME/go`
3. These paths need to be added in global path variable.

   `export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin`

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the go executable in your system path. which you can do by

```
export PATH=$PATH:/etc/usr/go/bin
```

You can put the same in /home/user/.profile

Answer (score 0):

just use asdf for installation. You can have several version also :D

Docs: https://asdf-vm.com/#/core-manage-asdf

Answer (score 0):

downlaod the installer form [enter link description here](https://golang.org/dl/), choose intaller for linux that suit your device and then you go to your CLI and use `wget` or `curl` :

```
$ wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1...
```

and then extract the file to `/usr/local` :

```
$ tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1...
```

add path binary Go to `PATH` environment variable :

```
$ echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

and then use `go version` to check if the Go already installed

Answer (score 0):

**If You are using linux then open your terminal and run this command.**

`sudo apt install golang-go`

**This command will Install Go lang. in your system. ThankYou**

Answer (score 0):

**Steps for Go installation:**

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade    
wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.17.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvf go1.17.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo mv go /usr/local/
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
```

**Add in .bashrc**

```
vi .bashrc
export GOPATH="/root/go"
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$GOROOT/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score -1):

Download latest version from https://golang.org/doc/install

```sh
tar -xzf go1.15.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

move to `/usr/lib/` to folder with version number

```sh
sudo mv go /usr/lib/go-1.15
```

create symkink link on `/usr/bin/`

```sh
ln -s /usr/lib/go-1.15/bin/go /usr/bin/go
```