# Installing golang 1.10 on vagrant vbox

Tags: go, vagrant

I am running the following script from a Vagrantfile and everything is working fine. In the end, I see the output `go1.10 linux/amd64` as expected.
But, when I run `vagrant ssh` I get `The program 'go' is currently not installed`.

What is the difference between vagrant provision that was able to see `go` and `vagrant ssh` that was not able to see `go`?

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|

     s.inline = "
                sudo apt-get update 

                export GOPATH=$HOME/work
                sudo curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.10.linux-amd64.tar.gz
                sudo tar -xvf go1.10.linux-amd64.tar.gz
                sudo mv go /usr/local

                sudo echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin' >> ~/.profile
                export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
                go version" # this row is working fine on the script but not after ssh

   end
```

Comment: Is the provisioning script run under the same user you SSH into? If not, add the `PATH` to `/etc/profile` instead of `~/.profile`

Comment: @mhutter I don't know. This is new to me. I just run vagrant ssh

Comment: Find out by adding `id` or `whoami` to the script ;-)

Comment: @mhutter  the user running the provision is root. and the user im using is vagrant - what sould i do? I want go to be available for all users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554817/golang-installation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make your changes to `$PATH` available to all users, you have to change it in the global profile, not the user's. Change the line

```
sudo echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin' >> ~/.profile
```

to

```
sudo echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin' >> /etc/profile
```